# Issue in creating image for a simple view

Tags: kognitio-wx2, kognitio

DB is really fast .. 
But one particular simple view is getting hung when I try to create the image for it.
Have tried creating images for complex views and got succeeded.

Any specific reasons ?

Comment: Please post an example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good article on the Kognitio forums at http://www.kognitio.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=12 which outlines a number of ways to investigate performance issues.

It covers common problems such as:

1. locking
2. queueing
3. user errors such as missing join conditions
4. table fragmentation on disk for disk-based queries
5. concurrent activity
6. skew

It also highlights extra information to capture should the above information not be adequate to resolve the problem.